# Galaxy S8: Set default app for left swipe?

Tags: samsung, default-applications, samsung-galaxy-s-8

Is it possible to set a default app to open on left swipe on Home screen? Currently Bixby app opens on left swipe, I would like to change it to some other app.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [Bixby Button Remapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phascinate.bixbybuttonremapper) or disable Bixby on left Swipe:

- Enter edit mode for Galaxy S8 home screen(long tap on homescreen)
- Switch to Bixby Home page
- In the Bixby Home (Hello Bixby)  page, you can find the switch in the top right

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is only possible to change the app on left swipe by installing an app called Bixby Remapper.